# Disabling all UITableView cells except the last one - Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, cell

Currently working with UITableView in swift.

Since my table cell values are appending by clicking the button i want to figure out a way to disable interaction for all the previous cells, except the last one.

I've played with array-based approach a little, but it didn't work out the way i wanted.

```
var disabledRows = [0,1,2]
        else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    }

    if (contains(disabledRows, indexPath.row)) {
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
    }
    else {
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }
```

The issue with this approach is that i have to count all cells and then block the last one.

Maybe there are some easier approaches?

Any help much appreciated.

Update - here is my complete "cellForRowAtIndexPath" function

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath
    indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell: CustomCellForTableViewTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! CustomCellForTableViewTableViewCell

    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    }

    if (contains(disabledRows, indexPath.row)) {
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
    }
    else {
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    let quest = arrayOfQuestions[indexPath.row]
    cell.setCell(type.Grocery, optionno1:type.option1, optionno2:type.option2)

    cell.mainText.text = type.Grocery


    cell.optionOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    return cell

}
```

Comment: You can simply compare the indexPath to the datasource object's length

Comment: and how do i do that?

Comment: Could you post the complete cellForRowAtIndexPath: method?

Comment: Why do you want to disable user interaction in the first place ? Is this a custom cell with buttons or gesture recognizers that you want to disable all together or are you just trying to disable the selection of these cells ? For the second case, there is indeed an easier approach.

Comment: yes, its a custom-cell with unbuttons, which i want to disable. the selection is already disabled

Comment: @ZeMoon the complete cellForRowAtIndexPath method is in the post

Comment: Then use @ZeMoon solution. The UITableView has method numberOfRowsInSection. Use it and then just test if indexPath.row is equal to numberOfRows - 1 (index of the last cell).

Comment: im not really following how do i get the numberOfRows - is it a variable? because when i use it in the code i get an error

Comment: tableview.numberOfRowsInSection(0) assuming your table only has one section

Comment: worked out perfectly! thank you @deadbeef and Will M. for great support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath: method.

```
if (indexPath.row == yourDataSourceArray.count - 1) {
// enable cell
} else {
// disable cell
}
```

Comment: how do i understand what is "yourDataSourceArray" - all of the options i've  used return "no member named count error" ?

Comment: yourDataSourceArray is the data source of your table view. You use the numberOfRowsInSection method in which you provide a count of rows, so the yourDataSourceArray.count is that count.